Is there value in developing a 'physical/relativstic' QIT (discussion)?
My motivation for asking this question is that I've recently been captivated by representation theory and I am incredibly interested in studying the symmetries behind different the operators in QIT.
That being said, I've mainly encountered applications of representation theory in QFT, where the theory develops naturally from the various possibilities allowed under Lorentz (think spinor representation for ex).
This all leads to my (perhaps misguided) problem: Information Theory isn't defined off of physical phenomena, and I am perturbed by the idea that there aren't constraints to 'guide' me through understanding which operators are physically realizable. (For example I would expect there to exist some relationship between the Bell inequality and the fact that the Lorentz group isn't connexe).
What I'm wondering is whether there is  value in developing QIT based off of the distinguishable properties of fundamental interactions (for example using ee scattering to create entangled spin states)? I have a hard time imagining how information can exist in a different matter.
My 'hope' is that this would introduce more constraints to the symmetries under which information can transform and allow for a more fundamental study of information.
